# Как сделать редирект в js?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! Возникла такая проблема. Не работает редирект в js

```
<a id="aaa" onclick="href();" href="#"></a>
```

Пробовал этими способами, но ничего не помогает

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
    function href() {
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    document.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com'
    }
</script>
```

Comment: а почему просто href не установить ссылки? зачем яваскрипт тут?

Comment: кстати, первым делом нужно смотреть ошибки в консоли браузера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что inline обработчики выполняются в контексте HTML элемента.

то есть, все, что используется, сначала ищется в html элементе, и в данном случае href - это свойство элемента `a`, а не функция.

Проверить это можно просто, достаточно поменять код на следующий

```html
<a id="aaa" onclick="console.log(this.href===href, href);" href="#">Нажми меня</a>
```

Для исправления - достаточно изменить имя функции обработчика:

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
  function func() {
    console.log('я делаю редирект');
    document.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
  }
</script>
<a id="aaa" onclick="func();" href="#">Нажми меня</a>
```

Либо навешивать обработчик с помощью функции [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
function func() {
  console.log('я делаю редирект');
  document.location.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
}
document.getElementById('aaa').addEventListener('click', func);
```

```html
<a id="aaa" href="#">Нажми меня</a>
```