# JavaScript редирект

Tags: javascript, wordpress, json

Здрaвствуйте. Есть форма на странице `example.com/contact`, которая отправляет данные по адресу `/wp-json/metform/v1/entries/insert/87`. В случае успешной отправки возвращается код ответа `200`.

Какой JS-код способен сделать редирект страницы, если при обращении к адресу `/wp-json/metform/v1/entries/insert/87` сервер ответил `200`?

Пример реализации:

1. Текущая страница `example.com/contact`
2. После нажатия Submit Button данные отправляются на `/wp-json/metform/v1/entries/insert/87`
3. JS-код, размещенный на странице, проверяет код ответа `/wp-json/metform/v1/entries/insert/87`
4. Если код ответа `200 OK` JS-код делает редирект на `example.com/success`

[image]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591320/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B2-js

Comment: Для формы случаем не плагин используешь? Какой?

Comment: @SeVlad использую плагин MetForm.

Comment: В [его](https://wordpress.org/plugins/metform/) описании я вижу: "Redirect after successful form submission: Simply add desired destination URL and redirect to that page after successfully submitting the form".  Так что изучай мануал по плагу и настраивай его.

Comment: @SeVlad спасибо за ответ. Да, я знаю, что там есть эта возможность, но мне так же нужно делать перенаправление в случае ошибки. А там такой возможности, к сожалению, нет.

Comment: В случае ошибки надо выводить сообщение на месте. Но в любом случае обработкой занимается плагин и поэтому обращайся к его документации или разработчикам.